# A question about the seventh formative criteria in Bourbaki's Theory of Sets

Tags: induction, meta-math

> CF7. Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a relation (resp. a term) in a theory
> $\mathcal{T}$, and let $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ be
> letters. Then  $(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{A}$ is a
> relation (resp. a term) in $\mathcal{T}$.

Is this supposed to be understood as one theorem formulated as follows: if  $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a relation, then $(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{A}$ is a relation and if  $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a term, then $(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{A}$ is a term? Judging by what the authors wrote in (a)

> and we know already that $\boldsymbol{A'_j}$ is a relation

the inductive step is the following statement:

> if $\boldsymbol{A_k}$ is a relation, then $\boldsymbol{A'_k}$ is a relation for and if $\boldsymbol{A_k}$ is a term, then $\boldsymbol{A'_k}$ is a term for $k=1,2,...,i-1$

Am I right? Maybe we should prove it as two different theorems with two respective inductive hypotheses? Why can we join them together in one theorem?[image]

[image]

Comment: First question: Yes. Bold A is a meta-variable used for a term or formula.

Comment: Second question: not clear...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is my version of the inductive hypothesis
>if $\boldsymbol{A_k}$ is a relation, then $\boldsymbol{A'_k}$ is a relation for and if $\boldsymbol{A_k}$ is a term, then $\boldsymbol{A'_k}$ is a term for $k=1,2,...,i-1$

correct? Did the authors mean this?

Comment: Yes; the two kinds are treated under a "general" approach. It seems useless... the only trick is that the operator $\tau$ is applied to a formula and produce a term.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA one more question if I may. It's about CF8. How to employ CS1 to show that $(\boldsymbol{T}|\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{A}$ is identical with $(\boldsymbol{x_1}|\boldsymbol{x'_1})(\boldsymbol{x_2}|\boldsymbol{x'_2})...(\boldsymbol{x_p}|\boldsymbol{x'_p})A$. Should we also use induction?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** 
 That is correct. In
Chapter 1 / 1.Terms and Relations / 1.Signs and Assemblies you can read the following:

> Let ***A*** and ***B*** be assemblies, and **x** be a letter. The assembly obtained by replacing **x**, whenever it occurs in ***A***, by the assembly ***B*** is denoted by (***B***|**x**)***A***

So, if A is a relation and contains the letter x, you are replacing the letter x with another letter y. This will not change the fact, that A is still a relation.

> and we know already that Aj′ is a relation

On page **22** below **CF7** *you can read "If Ai is preceded in the construction by a relation Aj, such that Ai is **not**(Aj), then Ai' is identical to with **not**(Aj') by **CS5** (which is (C|x)(not(A)) is identical with not(A')), and **not**(Aj') is a relation by **CF2**."* Following this trace backwards, "we know already that Aj' is a relation."

I'm also working my way through Bourbaki, so this is how I get it.